# Translate default ClaimsExchange error message

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

In one of my self-asserted technical profiles, I use a validation technical profile which calls a REST service. That service returns a 200 or 409 if all goes well, but it can also return a 500.
If that happens, the following message is shown:
[image]

I'm looking for a way to translate that message.
It's not using DefaultUserMessageIfRequestFailed and I can't seem to find it in the [default page level resources file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-flow-language-customization#customize-your-strings) either.
The docs also don't seem to specify anything concrete enough.

I'm assuming it's some kind of default message for when an orchestration step fails, or when any claims exchange fails, but I can't seem to find any details.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft is fixing the behavior for error code handling from rest apis. the recent changes you see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/restful-technical-profile#error-handling) are a result of that.

The bug fix for issue you are seeing will be rolled out in next 2-3 weeks. And then you should be able to use `DefaultUserMessageIfRequestFailed` or potentially some other metadata element to control this error message.

Comment: Thanks for your response Abhishek! The link you posted refers back to this post though :-) You probably wanted to link to something else?

Comment: Great, Thanks Abhishek. Any place I can follow up on this bug being fixed?

Comment: There is no public place to follow for bugs. I'll update here.

Comment: Hi Abhishek, I just tested this and it's working now! When the backend REST api returns a 500, then the DefaultUserMessageIfRequestFailed is shown now. Thank you!!

Comment: Glad, I lost my bounty though :)

Comment: Yes indeed. We should complain to StackOverflow for keeping those bounty-times so short ;-)